# Interact with running python script with PHP

Tags: php, bash

I have python script which may can ask for input while running (I must run it from PHP and can't modify python script). My question is, can I interact with that script with PHP. For example, run "python script.py" and then if last message is "String:", than insert input.

```
>> python script.py
>> Log 1 ...
>> Log 2 ...
>> Enter value A:
>> 2
>> Enter value B:
>> 4
```

i want to do this.

```
If(cmdlogtext == 'Enter value A:')
* Enter number 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To interact with running script you need to use `proc_open`.

[`proc_open` Official docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Below example is a simple usage.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array("file", "error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$process        = proc_open('python script.py', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to error-output.txt


    fwrite($pipes[0], 'Input 1' . PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'Input 2' . PHP_EOL);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
}
```

**Keep in mind:**
To send inputs to running script, you must use `fwrite` on `$pipes[0]`.
All parameters needs to be ended by `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I edited my question, as you can see. Can I do string compare of one line in log?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function and then inspect the output.

```
exec("python script.py", $output, $returnValue);
```

Edit: Re-read your question and I'm not sure about interactively providing input but you may be able to modify the `exec()` function to pass arguments to the Python script assuming the script can accept them.